# Error when displaying dialog pop up screen in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, popup, popupwindow

I have a problem -> I do some logic in angular js and when the logic is found something the user gets an error using dialog box from jquery ui.

In Angular function i need to display the pop up.

The pop up is displayed correctly but i get an error if i look in debug mode.
The error :
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply

I don't understand why is it happening?

my function in order to present pop up :

```
function dialogWithOneButton(message,title, callbackOnOK){
    var htmlString = "<div id=\"modalConfirm\" class=\"bold\" title=\""+title+"\">" + message + "</div>";
    var dialogButtons = {};
    var approveButtonText = messageToUser.dialogOkButton;

    dialogButtons[approveButtonText] =  {
                        text: approveButtonText,
                                        class:'btnApprove btnDialog onlyOneButton',
                                        click:function() {
                                            if (callbackOnOK)
                                                callbackOnOK();
                                            $(this).dialog("destroy");
                                        }
                                    };
    $(htmlString).dialog({
        height: 205,
        width:330,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons:dialogButtons
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue into Fiddle/Plunker? will help us a lot

Comment: this doesnt look error from the shown code..